# How do I edit the about page of my slack app?

Tags: slack, slack-api

How do I edit the about page of my Slack app (adding texts, screenshots,...)? In the documentation it says I can edit in Settings>Basic Information, but on this tab there are only the fields in the screenshot below:

[Apps Basic Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgDOz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that the **'Distribution Status'** of you app is `Publicly Distributed` ?

It seems like for 'Non Distributed' apps, slack does not allow to add much details.

Comment: My app is non distributed, it's "private"! And I discovered some days ago that that's why they don't let us add those extra informations :( Thank you for your help, Suyash!

Comment: Great, can you please mark the answer as ‘Accepted’ if it helped.